# Get-MsolUser to PowerShell GUI Textboxes

Tags: powershell

Trying to get all parameters to multiple PowerShell GUI Textboxes using this

```
    foreach($tenant in $tenants) { 


        foreach($parameter in $parameters) { 
            if($Customers.SelectedItem -eq $tenant.name) { 
                $indexeduser = Get-MsolUser -TenantId $tenant.TenantId -UserPrincipalName $Users.Selecteditem | select -Property $parameter

            New-Variable -Name "tb$parameter" -Value (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox) -Force
            (Get-Variable -Name "tb$parameter").Value.Text = "$indexeduser"
            (Get-Variable -Name "tb$parameter").Value.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,30)
            (Get-Variable -Name "tb$parameter").Value.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
            $form.Controls.Add((get-variable -Name "tb$parameter").Value)
            $i++

            if($i -eq 5 -or $i -eq 10 -or $i -eq 15 -or $i -eq 20 -or $i -eq 25 -or $i -eq 30 -or $i -eq 35 -or $i -eq 40 -or $i -eq 45) { 
                $x = $x + 160
                $y = 270
            }


            $y = $y + 30
            $y
            }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm only that it shows all the variables in the textbox as

```
@{Department=}
```

Can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Try `Select-Object -ExpandProperty $parameter`

Comment: `Microsoft.Online.Administration.User` Gives me this instead. So no work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by setting $indexeduser to $indexeduser.parameter

```
    foreach($tenant in $tenants) { 


        foreach($parameter in $parameters) { 
            if($Customers.SelectedItem -eq $tenant.name) { 
                $indexeduser = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName walter.kindblad@enzure.se | Select $parameter
                $indexeduser = $indexeduser.$parameter

            New-Variable -Name "tb$parameter" -Value (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox) -Force
            (Get-Variable -Name "tb$parameter").Value.Text = $indexeduser
            (Get-Variable -Name "tb$parameter").Value.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,30)
            (Get-Variable -Name "tb$parameter").Value.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
            $form.Controls.Add((get-variable -Name "tb$parameter").Value)
            $i++

            if($i -eq 5 -or $i -eq 10 -or $i -eq 15 -or $i -eq 20 -or $i -eq 25 -or $i -eq 30 -or $i -eq 35 -or $i -eq 40 -or $i -eq 45) { 
                $x = $x + 160
                $y = 270
            }


            $y = $y + 30
            $y
            }
    }
}
```